# Get a collection of the attributes of a nodeset

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a collection of nodes like this

```
<node id="1">
  <languaje>c</languaje>
  <os>linux</os> 
</node>
<node id="2">
  <languaje>c++</languaje>
  <os>linux</os> 
</node>
<node id="3">
  <languaje>c#</languaje>
  <os>window</os> 
</node>
<node id="4">
  <languaje>basic</languaje>
  <os>mac</os> 
</node>
```

And i want to create a new collection of all the properties id's like this

```
<root>
 <token>1</token>
 <token>2</token>
 <token>3</token>
 <token>4</token>
</root>
```

How can do that

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="*[node]">
  <root>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
  </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
  <token><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></token>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to store the result in a variable you can create a result tree fragment with XSLT 1.0 with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="rtf1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="m1"/>
</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*[node]" mode="m1">
      <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node" mode="m1"/>
      </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node" mode="m1">
      <token><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></token>
    </xsl:template>
```

Then you can do `<xsl:copy-of select="$rtf1"/>` to use the result tree fragment, or with 'exsl:node-set` you can process the created nodes with XPath and XSLT e.g.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf1)/root/token"/>
```

With XSLT 2.0 there are no longer result tree fragments so you can use the variable like any input without the need for an extension function.

Comment: Thanks .. so now how can i store the result in a variable ?

Comment: Well within XSLT 1.0 you could create a variable with a result tree fragment, with XSLT 2.0 with a temporary document, I will edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XQuery you can do it like this:

```
<root>
   { ($document/node/<node>{string(@id)}</node>) }
</root>
```

which is imho the clearest solution.

Otherwise you could create a string (not a document) containing your desired result with XPath 2 by concatenating the tags and your ids :

```
concat("<root>", string-join(for $i in /base/node/@id return concat("<node>",$i,"</node>"), " ") , "</root>")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap all the nodes under a tag, like <nodes> this works:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<root>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
</root>
</xsl:template>

<!-- templates -->
  <xsl:template match="node">
  <token><xsl:value-of select="@id" /></token>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested on XsltCake

http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/E937yH